# Optimize the loading of my Tumblr with JavaScript to customize styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

--
Hi !

Reader, if you are not comfortable with Tumblr, please tell me, I will give more details!

I had some issues on my tumblr page with the default theme 'Optica'. When I post an embed SoundCloud track, here is what I get on the page:

*photo below*

NOTE: I have tried to change the theme, and I discovered that for some of them, everything goes fine, but there are a few others with the same bug

So I've tried to fix that, and I've located the origin of the bug in the styles sheet main.css:

```
.video .video-wrapper {
background: #111;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56%;
height: 0;
}
```

The thing is, that to publish an embed code, you have to do it through the "Video post" tool on your tumblr dashboard, which then allows to style the embed code with the .video-wrapper

Of course, what I want to do here is reducing the bottom padding, but if I do it that way, it will affect all "Video posts". So I used the existing class .soundcloud_audio_player in the iframe to "mark" this type of Video posts to be able to change the styling only of these Video posts.

I have simplified it, and here is what it looks like at the end in browser:

```
<article class="audio not-page post-70801339374 " data-post-id="post_70801339374">
<div class="post-wrapper clearfix">
    <section class="post">
        <figure>
            <div class="video-wrapper">
                <iframe class="soundcloud_audio_player" />
            </div>
        </figure>
        <section class="attribution-tags clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://hymced.tumblr.com/tagged/SoundCloud" class="tag">SoundCloud</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://hymced.tumblr.com/tagged/Blutch" class="tag">Blutch</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </section>
    <section class="panel" />
</div>
<article>
```

And now, what I have put between  tags in my Tumblr customized HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.3");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("iframe.soundcloud_audio_player").parents('div.video-wrapper').css("padding-bottom", "17%");
    });
});
</script>
```

I used jQuery because I didn't know anything about JavaScript or jQuery before today, and I thought it what simpler! But maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, PROBLEM #1 FIXED!

**NOW, PROBLEM #2**

When the page  is loading, the former styling (before than JS intervene) appears for 1 or 2 sec (with my bandwidth anyway!) and it's quite ugly:

*photo below*

I've looked a bit here 
http://www.memodev.com/wiki/Optimiser_un_site_Web
and here
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro?hl=fr-FR

But I can't find how to improve the loading, and I hope some of you guys can :)

*PageSpeed test below*

Comment: The initial bug: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G02nd.png

Comment: The loading page: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MqWQf.png

Comment: The PageSpeed test: http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhymced.tumblr.com%2F

Comment: No I don't think it's a visual glitch. It's only because there is too much time between the moment the browser load the main.css file (in which bottom padding is specified at 56% for video posts) and the moment it run the jQuery script to change that value. I've tried several things but nothing works up to now...

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I'm a newbie with jQuery. I came to understand that my problem is in fact is my very jQuery code, which is not running the CSS changes at the right moment. I tried to remove the  `google.SetOnLoadCallBack` and run this function but it's not working      

`jQuery("main.css").ready(function() {         jQuery("iframe.soundcloud_audio_player").parents('div.video-wrapper').css("padding-bottom", "23%");
     });`

Comment: I guess it might be because the browser try to run the script whereas jquery isn't fully loaded... So maybe jQuery isn't a good workaround here, maybe JS is better, isn't ?

Comment: First because CSS selectors are not ascending, so I can't change the style of the elements 'div.video-wrapper' containing an 'iframe.soundcloud_audio_player' ONLY. Because there is also 'div.video-wrapper' elements without iframe.soundcloud_audio_player child, which I don't want to change.

Comment: @popnoodles I tried another thing this morning, but still not working: `<script type="text/javascript">       
function changeCSS() {
 document.getElementByClass("soundcloud_audio_player").parentNode.setAttribute("style","padding-bottom: 23%")
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", changeCSS(), false )
</script>`

Comment: Nobody on this please ? TO SIMPLIFY EVERYTHING, I WOULD JUST NEED A JS ONLY CODE THAT WILL ALLOW TO WAIT FOR THE MAIN.CSS STYLESHEET TO BE FULLY LOADED AND THEN IMMEDIATELY CHANGE A VALUE IN IT.

I've also noticed that something else is wrong but I'll come back to it later: the page is in 'infinite scroll' mode, and the changes don't affect the posts that are loaded after reaching the bottom of the first 'page'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to hide the fact that styles are changing after the page loads - 
So, this will do the trick very basically :

Add this to your HTML:
`<div id="screen"></div>`

Add this to your CSS :

```
div#screen {
     position:fixed;
     height:100%; width:100%; 
     background:white;
     z-index:999;
 }
```

You might not need the z-index
There are lots of [loaders](http://codepen.io/collection/HtAne/) you can use in place of this, if you would like -

and then,
In JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // Here, you insert that code that adds the padding to your iframe, and whatever else
    // you need to do to prepare the page... 
    $("#screen").hide();   // this will display your page - ! 
});
```